# How to change the soundcard output on-the-fly?

Tags: 12.10, sound, xubuntu, soundcard

One feature I miss the most in Windows 7, is the possibility to change the soundcard output on-the-fly. In Xubuntu 12.10, I have to unplug my headphones to make the sound come out of the speakers.

Is there a way to have a similar software level soundcard output switch with Xubuntu as with Windows 7?

[image: This is where you do the magic in Windows]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in sound control panel, but in ubuntu 12.04 in 12.10 this function seems broken.